# Responsive Centering HTML5

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

Okay, here it goes:

I am creating my first website. Immediately come across a problem which seems difficult to overcome.

I want to center my image between the header and footer which will stay centered vertically and horizontally, regardless of screen size.

I've seen examples using [flexbox](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/) where you can center text and whatnot in the middle of the target area. Seems like its useful. I tried it but maybe i haven't applied it correctly.

**My code so far**

```css
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans';

* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
}

body {
 color: grey;
 font-family: 'Alegreya', sans-serif;
 margin: 0;
}
img {
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 width: auto;
}
.banner {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 display: flex;
 display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
}
.banner-inner {
 max-width: 60%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
header {
 width: 100%;
 height: 80px;
 display: block;
}
#header-inner {
 max-width: 1200px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
/*--- START NAVIGATION --*/
nav {
 float: right;
 /* Top, Right, Bottom, Left */
 padding: 25px 20px 0 0;
}
#menu-icon {
 display: hidden;
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 background: url(img/nav.png) center;
}
a:hover#menu-icon {
 border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
ul {
 list-style-type: none;
}
nav ul li {
 font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', sans-serif;
 font-size: 150%;
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
 padding: 10px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
nav ul li a {
 color: grey;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: bolder;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
 color: lightgrey;
}
.current {
 color: black;
}
/* --- MUSIC PAGE --*/
.music-wrapper {
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}
.album-list figure {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 10%;
}
.album-list figcaption {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 150%;
 font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', sans-serif;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin: 2%;
}
.album-list a {
 text-decoration: none;
}
/* --- SOCIAL AND FOOTER --*/
footer {
 width: 100%;
}
.social {
 list-style-type: none;
 text-align: center;
}
.social li {
 display: inline;
}
.social i {
 font-size: 200%;
 margin: 0.5%;
 padding: 0.5% 4% 0.5% 4%;
 color: grey;
}
.social i:hover {
 color: lightgrey;
}
footer.second {
 max-height: 100px;
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0px;
 z-index: 10;
 background: white;
 
 border-top: 1px solid grey;
}
footer.second p {
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 text-align: center;
 color: grey;
 font-weight: bold;
}
/*---- MEDIA QUERIES---- */
@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
 header {
  position: absolute;
 }
 #logo {
  margin: 15px 0 20px -25px;
  background: url(img/SA_mobile.png) no-repeat center;
 }
 .banner {
  padding-top: 150px;
 }
 #menu-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #000000;
 }
 nav ul, nav:active ul {
  display: none;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  top: 60px;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 5px 0 5px 5px;
  width: 50%;
 }
 nav:hover ul {
  display: block;
  background: #FFF;
 }
 nav li {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
 }
 .social i {
  font-size: 150%;
  padding: 2% 4% 2% 4%;
 }
/*--- MUSIC PAGE --*/
.music-wrapper {
 padding-top: 25%;
 padding-bottom: 25%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
       
        <!--Content fits mobile screens-->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.12/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-G0fIWCsCzJIMAVNQPfjH08cyYaUtMwjJwqiRKxxE/rx96Uroj1BtIQ6MLJuheaO9" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>SPAZ Attack</title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <header>
      <div class="header-inner">
    <nav>
     <!--- Icon For Moblie Version -->
     <a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html" class="current">Home</a></li>
      <!--- Albums/Videos/Audio -->
      <li><a href="html/music.html">Music</a></li>
      <!--- Calander gig dates/book us -->
      <li><a href="html/gigs.html">Gigs</a></li>
      <!--- About the band -->
      <li><a href="html/bio.html">Bio</a></li>
      <!--- Merchandise -->
      <li><a href="html/merch.html">Merch</a></li>
      <!--- Contact Info -->
      <li><a href="html/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
    </nav>
      </div>
     </header>
<!--- END HEADER -->
  <section class="banner">
   <div class="banner-inner">
    <img src="img/spazAttackLogoSmaller1.png">
   </div>
  </section>
<!-- END BANNER -->
  
<!--- END FOOTER -->
 <footer class="second">
  <div>
   <ul class="social">
    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/spazattackband/" target="blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCXskFjQ_rPbJPzkXUHmrPtA?view_as=subscriber" target="blank"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://spazattack.bandcamp.com/" target="blank"><i class="fab fa-bandcamp"></i></a></li>
    <!-- Don't Have YET 
    <li><a href="#" target="blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" target="blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
    -->
   </ul>
  </div>
  <p>&copy; SPAZ Attack</p>
 </footer>
<!--- END SOCKET -->
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I would fix a height to the section with javascript. You can find out the size of the screen minus the size of the header and the size of the footer, then it is the size you want your section to take. When you find out that height, you can change your css height dynamically and do the flexbox vertical alignment.
(total - header - footer) = SectionHeight.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8cyjc9qw/

```css
.mid {
  height: 70vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

I have used some other examples to demonstrate how it would look. I have used vh for header and footer and assign the remaining height to main content section and use flexbox to center the image. Hope this helps.

Comment: Looks like a very straight forward solution. I must look into 'vh'. Thank you.

Comment: @2k9sandman, if you can upvote the answer, would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately my reputation is below 15 which prevents my votes from counting. Apologies @PKA